# FDMemTable perdendo dados ao utilizar o Filter

Tags: delphi, filtro, filter

Eu criei um FDMemTable, em tempo de execução, com a seguinte estrutura:

```
Cds_NaMenu := TFDMemTable.Create(nil);
Cds_NaMenu.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger);
Cds_NaMenu.FieldDefs.Add('MN_TELA_CODIGO', ftInteger);
Cds_NaMenu.FieldDefs.Add('MN_MENU_PESQUISA', ftString, 500);
Cds_NaMenu.FieldDefs.Add('DISPONIBILIDADE', ftInteger);
Cds_NaMenu.IndexDefs.Add('Ordem', 'MN_TELA_CODIGO', []);
Cds_NaMenu.CreateDataSet;
Cds_NaMenu.LogChanges := False;
Cds_NaMenu.IndexName := 'Ordem';
```

Carreguei os dados nele manualmente...

```
Cds_NaMenu.Append;
Cds_NaMenu.FieldByName('DISPONIBILIDADE').AsInteger := 1;
Cds_NaMenu.Post;
```

Bem. O problema acontece quando eu filtro o MemTable. Neste exato momento ele perde todos os dados. Ainda que eu retire o filtro, ele volta para RecordCount = 0. Mesmo salvando os dados em um xml, eles não estão visível. É como se realmente ele tivesse perdidos os dados em memória.

```
_recCount := Cds_NaMenu.RecordCount; // Result = 867;
Cds_NaMenu.Filter := 'DISPONIBILIDADE=1 AND MN_MENU_PESQUISA like ' + QuotedStr('%' + sTexto + '%');
Cds_NaMenu.Filtered := True;
_recCount := Cds_NaMenu.RecordCount; // Result = 0;
Cds_NaMenu.Filtered := False;
Cds_NaMenu.Filter := '';
_recCount := Cds_NaMenu.RecordCount; // Result = 0;
```

PS: Com ClientDataSet o mesmo código funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Testei com a mesma rotina que você postou e deu certo, não tais finalizando objeto do FDMemTable em algum momento?

Comment: Eu sei que não é resposta é suposição, mas talvez não estejas a preencher os dados completos (ou falte uma chave primária, ou não preenchas bem o campo do Index) e internamente só valide quando atua o filtro...

Comment: Também testei exatamente com o mesmo código que você postou e funcionou perfeitamente.